# how can i hide recaptcha overflow-y

Tags: javascript, html, css, recaptcha

Can someone please help me with recaptcha that have overflow-y visible, I use netlify form.

here its how its look like:
https://gyazo.com/76ae4df1ed119162bcda5566b956ce63

```
<form action="POST" data-netlify="true">
                <div class="fields">
                    <div class="field half">
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="field half">
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <input type="subject" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" rows="7"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="recaptcha" data-netlify-recaptcha="true" ></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="actions">
                    <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="button primary" /></li>
                </ul>
            </form>
```

Comment: You need to add the actual code of that `recaptcha`

Comment: maybe change your `overflow-y` to `hidden`?

Comment: nope, its not working, ive tried